# Screen Magnifier glass for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, magnifier.js

I am working on tielview and I need to implement magnifier when user touch the screen.

I tried with this https://github.com/nomanr/android-image-magnifier but didn't find any good solution.

What I want to achieve is, when the user does a long press on screen the magnifier show on left corner with zoom of the screen as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10LH6.jpg).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i need to show circle on left corner with zoom view  of that locations when user long press and move finger .
the image is there in question

Comment: i used this https://github.com/nomanr/android-image-magnifier   but this is for image i want to use on tileview

Comment: I just got idea making app like this, how far have you gone

Answer (score 1):

if you want to implement for single image view use this  https://github.com/xenione/loupe